# Setting default DisplayDateStart on all DatePickers

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

There is a set start date that I want to apply for every DatePicker in my app, because repeating the following snippet is not a good idea.

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"
            DisplayDateStart="05/01/2006"/>
```

As well as setting the default DisplayDateStart in one place I need to be able to bind the SelectedDate property of the DatePicker.

I have tried creating a custom UserControl, but pressing the calendar icon does nothing (well, the text box is flashing but no calendar pop-up appears)

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyWpfAdd.ModDatePicker"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DockPanel>
        DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker" DisplayDateStart="05/01/2006"/>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

With underlying code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyWpfApp
{
  public partial class ModDatePicker : UserControl
  {
    public DateTime? SelectedDate
    {
      get => (DateTime?)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty);
      set
      {
        this.DatePicker.SelectedDate = value;
        SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value);
      }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(ModDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public DateTime? DisplayDateEnd
    {
      get => (DateTime?)GetValue(DisplayDateEndProperty);
      set
      {
        this.DatePicker.DisplayDateEnd = value;
        SetValue(DisplayDateEndProperty, value);
      }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayDateEndProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayDateEnd", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(ModDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ModDatePicker()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all create a class with a static property which provides for the default date that you need:

```
public static class DatePickerHelper
{
    private static DateTime defaultDisplayDateStart = new DateTime(2006, 1, 5);

    public static DateTime DefaultDisplayDateStart
    {
        get
        {
            return defaultDisplayDateStart;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in a global default style for `DatePicker`s:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"

             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DatePicker}}">
            <Setter Property="DisplayDateStart" Value="{x:Static local:DatePickerHelper.DefaultDisplayDateStart}" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I hope this hint can help you

Answer (score 1):

The PropertyMetadata object takes default value as first argument. Specify your date there...

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyWpfApp
{
  public partial class ModDatePicker : UserControl
  {
    public DateTime? SelectedDate
    {
      get => (DateTime?)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty);
      set
      {
        this.DatePicker.SelectedDate = value;
        SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value);
      }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(ModDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public DateTime? DisplayDateEnd
    {
      get => (DateTime?)GetValue(DisplayDateEndProperty);
      set
      {
        this.DatePicker.DisplayDateEnd = value;
        SetValue(DisplayDateEndProperty, value);
      }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayDateEndProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayDateEnd", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(ModDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(new DateTime(2006,5,1)));

    public ModDatePicker()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```